Force cloudFlare Turnstile to display the challenge checkbox
I am implementing CloudFlare Turnstile with a web form, and I need it to always display the challenge checkbox and force the user to check it. I don't want cloudFlare algorithm to decide and check the challenge checkbox for the user. It seems like this is possible to do evident by CloudFlare's own login form where the checkbox seem to always display (https://dash.cloudflare.com/login). Any ideas on how to do this? A sample code is much appreciated. Thanks!

I am implementing Turnstile widget explicitly
I have tried the widget mode as 'Managed'
This is a LAMP system with PHP, HTML, Javascript running on a Linux box

